# How to distinguish between CLI & CGI modes in Perl

Tags: perl, cgi, command-line-interface

I am supposed to write a Perl script which can be run both on the command line and as a CGI  script. I haven't been able to determine how I should distinguish between the two modes.

So could you please let me know how to implement the logic?

Answer (score 8):

You can check for the presence of any number of [CGI environment variables](http://oreilly.com/openbook/cgi/ch02_02.html), e.g.:

```
if ($ENV{GATEWAY_INTERFACE})
{
      print "Content-type: text/plain\n\nLooks like I'm a CGI\n";
}
else
{
      print "I'm just a plain command line program\n";
}
```

Comment: This is a bad resource, it does not list the mandatory [`GATEWAY_INTERFACE`](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc3875.html#4.1.4.).

Comment: @daxim: thanks; I've replaced the link with a better resource.

Answer (score 2):

At a guess, `$ENV{'GATEWAY_INTERFACE'}` will be NULL when run from the command line, and contain something (e.g. 1.1) when run as a CGI.

You'll need to try it out.

Comment: Err, why have I been voted down?  My suggestion doesn't sound too ridiculous.  Could have least have left a comment you coward...

Comment: Upvote for you, you have the better answer in terms of robustness and expressing the intention to the maintenance programmer.

Comment: @daxim Thanks, was beginning to doubt my albeit very rusty Perl knoweldge.

Answer (score 1):

Since it's a common question, I want to point out that there are more than two cases people might be interested in. For a more all-purpose solution:

```
use IO::Interactive qw( is_interactive );

if (exists $ENV{'GATEWAY_INTERFACE'}) {
    # running as CGI
}
elsif (is_interactive()) {
    # running from terminal, with a real live user
}
else {
    # running from cron, system call, etc
}
```

If you're prompting the user for input, it's the second case that you want to check. And before you start writing your own implementation of `is_interactive()` you should probably look at [this post](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=472934) by the author of the [`IO::Interactive`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/IO-Interactive/) module.