# How can I tell if a Perl script is executing in CGI context?

Tags: perl, cgi

I have a Perl script that will be run from the command line and as CGI. From within the Perl script, how can I tell how its being run?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1914966/how-can-i-determine-if-a-script-was-called-from-the-command-line-or-as-a-cgi-scri http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3086655/in-perl-how-to-distiniguish-between-cli-cgi-mode

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to distinguish between CLI & CGI modes in Perl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3086655/how-to-distinguish-between-cli-cgi-modes-in-perl)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The best choice is to check the `GATEWAY_INTERFACE` environment variable. It will contain the version of the CGI protocol the server is using, this is almost always `CGI/1.1`. The `HTTP_HOST` variable mentioned by Tony Miller (or any `HTTP_*` variable) is only set if the client supplies it. It's rare but not impossible for a client to omit the `Host` header leaving `HTTP_HOST` unset.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use constant IS_CGI => exists $ENV{'GATEWAY_INTERFACE'};
```

If I'm expecting to run under mod_perl at some point I'll also check the `MOD_PERL` environment variable also, since it will be set when the script is first compiled.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use constant IS_MOD_PERL => exists $ENV{'MOD_PERL'};
use constant IS_CGI      => IS_MOD_PERL || exists $ENV{'GATEWAY_INTERFACE'};
```

Answer (score 6):

You would best check the GI in the CGI.

```
use CGI qw( header );

my $is_cgi = defined $ENV{'GATEWAY_INTERFACE'};

print header("text/plain") if $is_cgi;
print "O HAI, ", $is_cgi ? "CGI\n" : "COMMAND LINE\n";
```

Comment: You can skip the quotes: my $is_cgi = defined $ENV{GATEWAY_INTERFACE};

Comment: This worked on me. defined is the thing that works on my side, I am using perl 5. Upvoting for this solution

Answer (score 3):

One possible way is to check environment variables that are set by web servers.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

our $IS_CGI = exists $ENV{'HTTP_HOST'};
```

Answer (score -1):

See if your program is connected to a TTY or not:

```
my $where = -t() ? 'command line' : 'web server';
```

Comment: -1: Incorrect. This will tell you whether the program is running interactively, not whether it's running under CGI. Being called from a cron job or as part of a shell pipeline would give incorrect results (it would be non-interactive, but also non-CGI).