# Using both ARGV and CGI in a Perl script

Tags: perl, command-line, parameters, cgi

I am writing a Perl script that can run both from command line and from a web page. The script receives a couple of parameters and it reads those parameters through **$ARGV** if it started from command line and from **CGI** if it started from a web page. How can I do that?

```
my $username;
my $cgi = new CGI;
#IF CGI
$username = $cgi->param('username');
#IF COMMAND LINE
$username = $ARGV[0];
```

Comment: The standard-compliant variable to check against is called `GATEWAY_INTERFACE`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1914966/how-can-i-determine-if-a-script-was-called-from-the-command-line-or-as-a-cgi-scr http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3086655/in-perl-how-to-distiniguish-between-cli-cgi-mode http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4853948/how-can-i-tell-if-a-perl-script-is-executing-in-cgi-context

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The cleanest way might be to put the meat of your code in a module, and have a script for each interface (CGI and command line).

You could test for the presence of CGI environment variables (`$ENV{SERVER_PROTOCOL}`) to see if CGI is being used, but that would fail if the script is used as a command-line script from another CGI script.

If all you want to pass via `@ARGV` are form inputs, keep in mind that CGI (the module) will check the `@ARGV` for inputs if the script is not called as a CGI script. See the section entitled "DEBUGGING" in the [documentation](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?CGI).

Comment: I guess you're right, in fact I am going to create a core module and two separate interfaces, thank you to all of you guys :)

Answer (score 9):

With [CGI.pm](https://metacpan.org/module/CGI) you can pass params on the command line with no need to change your code. Quoting the docs:

> If you are running the script from the command line or in the perl
>   debugger, you can pass the script a list of keywords or
>   parameter=value pairs on the command line or from standard input (you
>   don't have to worry about tricking your script into reading from
>   environment variables)

Wrt your example, it's a matter of doing:

```
perl script.cgi username=John
```

Answer (score 6):

[Mojolicious framework](https://github.com/kraih/mojo/blob/master/lib/Mojo/Command.pm#L90) uses battle-proven environment autodetection that works on different servers (not Apache only).

So you can use following code:

```
if (defined $ENV{PATH_INFO} || defined $ENV{GATEWAY_INTERFACE}) {
    # Go with CGI.pm
} else {
    # Go with Getopt::Long or whatever
}
```

Answer (score 3):

When invoked through CGI your script will additional [environment variables](http://www.cgi101.com/book/ch3/text.html) set. You can use them in your if condition.

For example, you could use **HTTP_USER_AGENT**

```
if ( $ENV{HTTP_USER_AGENT} )
{
   #cgi stuff
}
else
{
   #command line
}
```

But if your real need is to test a CGI script stand alone, Try ActiveState Komodo, The debugger lets to **[Simulate CGI Environment](http://docs.activestate.com/komodo/4.4/debugger.html#Debugging_Options_General)**